# Convert timestamp to dateTime in MarkLogic

Tags: xquery, marklogic-10

I am using `xdmp:document-timestamp` function to get the timestamp of the most recent update that happened on this document.

Above function returns timestamp as output like: `16222984921692864`.

How can I convert this timestamp `16222984921692864` to the human readable `xs:dateTime`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the [`xdmp:timestamp-to-wallclock`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:timestamp-to-wallclock) function to convert timestamp to dateTime.

```
xdmp:timestamp-to-wallclock(16222984921692864)
```

returns:

```
2021-05-29T10:28:12.1692864
```